# Has the position of moderators towards new age gurus evolved?

Tags: discussion

When I go through the comments of one of the moderators in [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/validity-of-references-from-new-age-gurus/), it seems that it is okay to cite new age gurus if the question is not specifically looking for answers from scriptures. But on the main site, this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44818/18974) has cited Sadhguru and has a citation banner.

Can someone clarify if answers citing new-age gurus are no longer valid ? If so, what's the criterion to determine new-age guru ? Do popular figures in Hinduism from 19th century also fall in the same bucket ?

In my mind it should depend upon the person asking the question whether he is okay with new-age gurus. But if the question does not specify then what is the approach ? Is the approach going to be that of citation banner. To be honest, I am fine with the citation banner. Just want clarity for future.

Answer (score 7):

Citation banner was added because content of answer is different from what Sadhguru says. Only few things what OP said can be found in Sadhguru's page. Some part of answer, like on untouchables, different organs of creator, still needs sources.

**Can someone clarify if answers citing new-age gurus are no longer valid ? If so, what's the criterion to determine new-age guru ? Do popular figures in Hinduism from 19th century also fall in the same bucket ?**

As said in [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2144/3500), all Hindu Gurus and Acharyas are allowed given they don't go against very core ideas of hinduism.

Comment: The answer being discussed here has simply posted a link to a website. But he has to quote the portions from the article to validate the points (he has made) which he has not done. Of course he is new to the site and will learn these things gradually but I'm asking in such cases where just a link is added to an answer but portions are not quoted from the reference in the answer itself can we still add citation needed banner?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, If OP doesn't quote anything from "reference" he quoted as primary source, then  citation banner will be added. It is not like OP can write his opinions as answers and add some link in answer for sake of reference.

Comment: So, even if Sathguru is a valid source, for that reason you mentioned the banner should be added.

Comment: @Rickross yes..